# Multiple events at once with pure javascript?

Tags: javascript

Is there any shorter way of doing this with pure javascript?

```
temp_thumbImage.onload = function () {
    drawThumbnails();
};

temp_thumbImage.onerror = function () {
    drawThumbnails();
};
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can cascade assignments if you want to set multiple things to the same value:

```
temp_thumbImage.onload = temp_thumbImage.onerror = drawThumbnails;
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to make a function call in a function expression, just use the function as event handler:

```
temp_thumbImage.onload = drawThumbnails;
temp_thumbImage.onerror = drawThumbnails;
```